# Traced SVG Image loading in React

Tags: reactjs, svg, gatsby

I recently saw `traced SVG image loading` in `gatsby.js`

https://medium.com/workshop-me/traced-svg-images-for-excellent-ux-d75a6bb4caed

Is there any way in which i can implement this in `create-react-app`, with automation. 
Right now,
I use `create-react-app` and `cloudinary`. I store the `url` in my database, 
I couldn't find a good resource through which I can make this happen.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the post and what it uses, you find that it uses https://github.com/lovell/sharp, which accepts an image as parameter, in your case you can download the image, apply the filter and finally use the most important part of this technique:

```
<div
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url("${realUrl}"), url("${
          tracedSVG
        }")`,
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

Then the browser will do the dynamic load for you.